# How to monkey patch django function?

Tags: python, django

I want to customize django admin `change_list_result` row content, so i guess override related to  `change_list_result` function.

And I found to konw call `display_for_field` via `items_for_result` in `django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list`. [admin_list.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f52022ad96356d4b1061610f2b74ea4d1956a608/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L241)

I put following code to the `manage.py`, but doesn't work.

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import display_for_field
from warehouse.monkey_patching import _display_for_field_mod

display_for_field = _display_for_field_mod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you override the *local* variable `dispaly_for_field`. If you want to override it, you need to set the attribute of the module:

```
from django.contrib.admin import utils
from warehouse.monkey_patching import _display_for_field_mod

utils.display_for_field = _display_for_field_mod
```

As you probably already know, you must make sure that you monkey patch the function *before* other modules import it, since otherwise, these will obtain a reference to the "old" function. You thus probably should import this as (one of the) first lines in your `manage.py` file.

Comment: Because here we alter the function in the module, not the *local* identifier.